# Why is layout of collectionView cell diverse when it is supposed to be the same?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout

When i was creating my collection view, i defined cell to be the same with the same layout

```
class FriendsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    fileprivate let cellId = "cellId"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Recent"
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.register(FriendCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }


}

class FriendCell: BaseCell {

    override func setupViews() {

        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(dividerLineView)
        profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "zuckprofile")

        setupContainerView()

        addConstraintsWithFormat( "H:|-12-[v0(68)]|", views: profileImageView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat( "V:[v0(68)]", views: profileImageView)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        addConstraintsWithFormat( "H:|-82-[v0]|", views: dividerLineView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat( "V:[v0(1)]|", views: dividerLineView)



    }
    func setupContainerView() {
        let containerView = UIView()
        addSubview(containerView)

        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-90-[v0]|", views: containerView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(  "V:[v0(50)]", views: containerView)
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(messageLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(timelabel)
        containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat( "H:|[v0][v1]|", views: nameLabel, timelabel )
        containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat( "V:|[v0][v1(24)]|", views: nameLabel, messageLabel)
        containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat( "H:|[v0]-12-|", views: messageLabel )
        containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(20)]|", views: timelabel)
    }

}

extension UIView {
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String , views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

So as it seems from the code everything in cells shout be the same. With the same layout, constraints etc
Then i got this terrible result.[image]

Please maybe someone knows ***why*** this behavior take place here?

Comment: Can you show what you expected them to look like?

Comment: I expecting to see all the green and brown strips to be the same size in all cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in ambiguity between `nameLabel` and `timeLabel` intrinsic size and their content hugging priority and content compression resistance priority (check [this article](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-content-hugging-and-content-compression-resistance-priorities-476fb5828ef)).

You have two options, either set following horizontal compression resistance and hugging priority for both labels in `setupContainerView`:

```
nameLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
nameLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
timeLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
timeLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

Which will make the `timeLabel` to keep the size according to its content and the `nameLabel` will take the rest of the content (meaning that if the time is not set, the `timeLabel` will be shrinked to width 0, and the rest will be taken up by `nameLabel`).

Or set an explicit width for one of those labels, e.g.:

```
timeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

**EDIT**

According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AmbiguousLayouts.html),

> When an ambiguous layout occurs at runtime, Auto Layout chooses one of the possible solutions to use. This means the layout may or may not appear as you expect. Furthermore, there are no warnings written to the console, and there is no way to set a breakpoint for ambiguous layouts.

Or [other doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html):

> When stretching a series of views to fill a space, if all the views have an identical content-hugging priority, the layout is ambiguous. Auto Layout doesn’t know which view should be stretched.

None of the docs I was able to find tells us, how does the Auto Layout solve this issues - and I believe the reason is to make sure we won't be relying on this and rather explicitly set the priorities. Therefore, the label that gets stretched (even the size to which it is stretched) can be really chosen by any random algorithm. Based from your result we can at best conclude, that probably it is not based on the order in which labels were added as subviews.

Comment: so if the problem is ambiguity then why it is laying differently just only one cell in cells array then the rest cell laying with the same concept? Didn't they are suppose to be the same no matter what king of ambiguity in cell layout would be exist?

Comment: @N.Khasanov I would expect so, but in case of ambiguity the behavior is undefined, so I guess this can possibly happen. Just try using my suggestions, and if this helps we can at least be sure that this is the root cause.

Comment: everything you wrote works. but anyway( if i could to know the internal default rules of preferring this or that particular way to represent views. cause i had "same" pain in the a*s regarding default internal content hugging priority in visual formatting language when i use two UILabels and add constraint like "H|[v0][v1]|" so system is some preferring one label above the other( but when i just add smallest clarifying inessential detail like "H|-[v0][v1]| or "H|[v0][v1]-|" system makes content hugging priority parameter same for two labels simultaneously

Comment: @N.Khasanov You should never rely on internal working of the autolayout - that's why it's internal. Apple docs (see my updated answer) are very careful not to reveal anything about how the autolayout solves this ambiguity - and those same docs explicitly tell us to always set the priority explicitly. And I must say - if I was implementing this, I would use `arc4random` to chose the constraint to break really randomly, so that the library user would be forced to follow my docs.

Comment: it seems you are right. thank you very much, you helped me a lot